# Read kafka topic to the end using reactive api

Tags: java, apache-kafka, project-reactor

We are using compacted kafka topic to store state changes and during restart or rebalance need to restore state by reading the topic to the end and take the last entry for every key.

For non-reactive consumers we could

```
// get assigned partitions
Set<TopicPartition> assignment = consumer.assignment();
// get "end" offset for every partition
Map<TopicPartition, Long> endOffsets = consumer.endOffsets(assignment);

// poll data until "end" is reached for every partition
...
```

This is what what kafka connect is doing for SourceTask behind the scene.

But what would be the right way to do it using [reactive kafka api](https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference)? We could access underlining consumer using [doOnConsumer](https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference) but how to propagate this information through the reactive pipeline?

***Update***

Here is my code with comments. `TopicPartitionMap` is an additional structure that helps to signal and validate partitions end in O(1) time.

```
public Flux<ReceiverRecord<K, V>> readToEnd() {
    return consumer.receive()
            // cache value to get metadata once
            .concatMap(record -> getEndOffsets().cache()
                    .flatMap(offsets -> getPosition(record.receiverOffset().topicPartition())
                            .map(position -> new TopicPartitionRecord<>(record, position, offsets))
                    )
            )
            // wait until end is reached for all partitions
            .takeUntil(record -> record.partitionMap.allSet())
            .map(partitionRecord -> {
                ReceiverRecord<K, V> record = partitionRecord.getRecord();
                TopicPartition topicPartition = record.receiverOffset().topicPartition();

                // need to check consumer position (not record offset)
                if (partitionRecord.consumerPosition >= partitionRecord.partitionMap.offset(topicPartition)) {
                    // flag that end is reached for the corresponding partition
                    partitionRecord.partitionMap.set(topicPartition);
                }
                return record;
            });
}

public Mono<Long> getPosition(TopicPartition partition) {
    return consumer
            .doOnConsumer(consumer -> consumer.position(partition));
}

public Mono<TopicPartitionMap> getEndOffsets() {
    return consumer
            .doOnConsumer(consumer -> {
                Set<TopicPartition> assignment = consumer.assignment();
                Map<TopicPartition, Long> offsets = consumer.endOffsets(assignment);
                return new TopicPartitionMap(offsets);
            });
}
```

Comment: Might be worth adding a few other relevant tags (kafka, java, etc.) - I've assumed you've used Java here but the extra clarification can't hurt :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a `KafkaReceiver<Object, Object> receiver`, you should be able to do something like:

```
receiver.receive()
        .zipWith(receiver.doOnConsumer(Consumer::assignment)
                .flatMap(a -> receiver.doOnConsumer(c -> c.endOffsets(a)))
                .filter(m -> !m.isEmpty())
                .single()
                .retry()
                .cache()
                .repeat())
        .groupBy(t -> t.getT1().partition())
        .flatMap(f -> f.filter(t -> t.getT1().offset()+1 == (long) t.getT2().get(new TopicPartition(topic, f.key()))))
        .map(t -> t.getT1())
```

A few notes on why I've done it this way:

- This gives you a `Flux<ReceiverRecord>`, the last `ReceiverRecord` in each partition.
- Usually I'd say don't create a separate variable for the receiver, just inline it all - but it's impossible to do that using `doOnConsumer()`, which is necessary here since `assignment()` isn't supported via the reactive `KafkaReceiver` directly.
- I usually try to avoid using `zipWith()` to essentially merge a `Flux` and a repeated cached `Mono`, favouring using `flatMapMany()` instead. However, in this case I don't think that will work, as you need to actively poll the topic before `assignment()` will return anything other than an empty set.

Comment: Also found the solution using similar code with some corrections - I used `concatMap` with cache for endOffset Mono, get consumer position using `doOnConsumer ` instead record offset to check the end and `takeUntil` to complete publisher. Will post my code